# spree OR solidus where are the events listed

Tags: solidus

If I'm reading the documentation correctly, one way to customize the behavior
of spree is to listen to fired events. One event is "order_finalized".

From where can I get a list of events that my spree application "fires/ supports"?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the events fired by default in Solidus are:

- `order_finalized`
- `reimbursement_reimbursed`
- `reimbursement_errored`

Events are in an experimental phase. That's the reason why there is a small number of events currently but they are used in production by several stores and Solidus welcomes Pull Requests that add more events when needed by developers.